# Convert JSON object to string without JSON

Tags: javascript, json

This is my server response:

```
{"names":["Kreisler","Kreisler","Kreisler"]} .
```

If I use the above JSON response in JavaScript, I am getting an 'object' datatype

as `[object Object]`. Instead of getting Object type, I want to get the JSON response in string format.

Note: I don't have JSON js from my html.so I will not be able to use

```
JSON.stringify({"names":["Kreisler","Kreisler","Kreisler"]}).
```

Or let me know how can I install JSON here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  #<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {

      ss = {"names":["Kreisler","Kreisler","Kreisler"]}

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ss;
    }
  </script>


</html>
```

Comment: This is confusing, why would you want a string rather than the object in javascript, usually it's the other way around ?

Comment: Why you can't just use _JSON.stringify_ ? How do you mean by you don't have JSON js in your HTML?

Comment: Can you try  $.param(jsonObj)

Comment: if it is a server response, it will already be a string - you would have to parse or *shudder*  eval it first. In your example, you start with an object - so you need to stringify it one way or another. But why?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  #<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button></br>
  <div id="demo"></div>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {

      var ss = JSON.stringify({"names":["Kreisler","Kreisler","Kreisler"]});

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ss;
    }
  </script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible ways to solve your problem. The first is simply to examine how you are making your request to the server. Chances are that you can stop parsing the response to JSON and instead keep it a string.

If you don't have any control over that portion of the code, you will have to `stringify` the JSON object. You say that you don't have `JSON.stringify` available in the browser which is suspicious. `window.JSON` is a global and doesn't need to be "installed" at all. According to the MDN, `window.JSON` was available all the way back to IE 8:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

If you're using a custom browser implementation, the first option is probably your best.